# Поиск нужных ячеек в Excel по названию

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlrd

Есть алгоритм, который собирает в лист адреса всех ячеек, в которых упоминается определенный текст, но работает только с файлами xlsx на openpyxl. Есть-ли что-то такое для библиотеки xlrd? Сам файл я качаю по ссылке https://aparat.ua/cli/out.xls, с помощью библиотеки requests. Пытался сначала перевести его в формат xlsx с помощью библиотеки xls2xlsx, а потом уже работать с алгоритмом, но оно не работает...
P.s ещё тут используется модуль 're'

```
sheet_cells = []

answer = str(message.text) # в переменную answer помещается то, что ответил пользователь в ТГ

search_text = str(answer) # переменная, хранит в себе значение, которое мы ищем

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_to_file)  # Грузим наш прайс-лист
sheets_list = wb.sheetnames  # Получаем список всех листов в файле
sheet_active = wb[sheets_list[0]]  # Начинаем работать с самым первым
row_max = sheet_active.max_row  # Получаем количество столбцов
#print(type(row_max))
column_max = sheet_active.max_column  # Получаем количество строк

row_min = 1 # Переменная, отвечающая за номер строки
column_min = 1 # Переменная, отвечающая за номер столбца

while column_min <= column_max:
    row_min_min = row_min
    row_max_max = row_max
    while row_min_min <= row_max_max:
        row_min_min = str(row_min_min)

        word_column = get_column_letter(column_min)
        word_column = str(word_column)
        word_cell = word_column + row_min_min

        data_from_cell = sheet_active[word_cell].value
        data_from_cell = str(data_from_cell)
        regular = search_text
        result = re.findall(regular, data_from_cell)

        if len(result) > 0:
            sheet_cells.append(word_cell)
        # каждая ячейка, содержащая в себе нужное нам значение, помещается в лист

        else:
            await state.reset_state()
            
            

        row_min_min = int(row_min_min)
        row_min_min = row_min_min + 1
    column_min = column_min + 1
```

Comment: что конкретно не работает: ошибка или нерелевантный результат? Что вы ожидаете на выходе?

Comment: Если попытаться перевести в другой формат уже заранее скаченный файл, то работает. Когда, скачиваю его через python, он ругается примерно так "No <table> tags found - maybe this is Excel 5.0/95 format? If so, try using XLS2XLSX instead." Может быть я неправильно записываю его?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5Og7d7
Вот так я пытаюсь записать файл